# cURL request works on localhost but Connect() times out on server

Tags: php, curl

OK, so I apologise if this has been dealt with before, after searching for 30 minutes I couldn't find anything that exactly matched my issue.

I have a bit of a strange situation where a client is using an FTPS connection which I need to use cURL to download a file from. While running this EXACT script on my localhost the files download with no issue however once I place this on the server (our own hosting) the cURL returns a timeout error.

```
$remote = [
        filename => URL
    ];
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    foreach ($remote as $key => $file) {

        $targetFile = file formatted;
        $sourceFile = $file;
        $ftpuser = username;
        $ftppassword = password;

        echo $targetFile;

        // function settings
        $timeout = 10;
        $fileOpen = 'w';

        $curl = curl_init();
        $file = fopen($targetFile, $fileOpen);

          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $sourceFile);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $ftpuser . ':' . $ftppassword);

          // curl settings
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
          //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FTP_SSL, CURLFTPSSL_ALL);
          //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FTPSSLAUTH, CURLFTPAUTH_TLS);

          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
          curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);

          $result = curl_exec($curl);
          $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
          var_dump ($info);
          echo curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        fclose($file);
```

Comment: $sourceFile is undefined ... So your url is wrong.

Comment: check your `$targetFile` value `$sourceFile`

Comment: sorry updated the code to include the variables I have already set

Comment: Try setting this: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);` Some systems timeout immediately if this isn't set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added this to the options but didn't get any change! I'm stupidly confused by this

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the server is being blocked by a proxy server, preventing the connection from being established.

Comment: I know the hosting server is not proxy enabled. The FTP server is not blocking our IP either. I have tried it from another server and it immediately blocks the connection. The server that it is currently on gets through the firewall but then doesn't fulfil a connection

Comment: Are you sure the `$remote` array contains the data that you expect? Have you var_dumped it?

Comment: yeah the array is hard coded with filenames. an example of this would be "id" => "ftps://username@ip/filename.txt"

Comment: seemingly the curl_getinfo isn't returning much useful data. I just have the filename and primary IP, everything else is just 0

Comment: The line `$remote = [filename => URL];` is not valid, so I'm wondering how you are going on to process `$remote`

Comment: the line is pseudo, remote[] hold data like the pseudo I just commented. I don't want to put the actual data up.

this is how it actually looks:
$remote = ["file" => "ftps://user@x.x.x.x/file.txt","file" => "ftps://user@x.x.x.x/file.txt","file" => "ftps://user@x.x.x.x/file.txt"];